# How to change sharekit's actionSheetStyle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit 2.0 in my project, and can't for the life of me figure out how to change the actionSheetStyle for sharekit's default actionsheet to UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque or UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that if you present it via showFromToolbar:, it does not take actionSheetStyle other than UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic. Regardless of which one you specify. It might be a flaw in UIActionSheet.

Try to present it via some other method, e.g. showInView: